# Extracting elements from XML and turning into a dataset

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm stuck trying to shred some XML using T-SQL. Here's my XML (which some of you may recognise as coming from a deadlock graph):

```
<resource-list>
    <metadatalock subresource="DATA_SPACE" classid="data_space_id = 65601" dbid="7" id="lockb0553200" mode="X">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process806e5b88" mode="Sch-S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process11e2cb708" mode="Sch-M" requestType="convert" />
      </waiter-list>
    </metadatalock>
    <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="98099390" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="" id="lockbe2cfc00" mode="Sch-M" associatedObjectId="98099390">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process11e2cb708" mode="Sch-M" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process806e5b88" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
```

What I'd like to is extract a data set containing a row for each child of  (from there I'm fairly confident I can use the value() function to shred it further). In other words I want this 1-column, 2-row dataset:

```
 <metadatalock subresource="DATA_SPACE" classid="data_space_id = 65601" dbid="7" id="lockb0553200" mode="X">
   <owner-list>
     <owner id="process806e5b88" mode="Sch-S" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process11e2cb708" mode="Sch-M" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
 </metadatalock>
 <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="98099390" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="" id="lockbe2cfc00" mode="Sch-M" associatedObjectId="98099390">
   <owner-list>
     <owner id="process11e2cb708" mode="Sch-M" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process806e5b88" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
 </objectlock>
```

(I might not have explained this very well, basically I want the metadatalock node in row 1 and the objectlock node in row 2).

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT  XEventData.XEvent.query('/')
FROM    #resourceList
CROSS APPLY [resource-list].nodes('//resource-list/') AS XEventData ( XEvent )
```

but that only returns an error:

> Msg 9341, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   XQuery [#resourceList.resource-list.nodes()]: Syntax error near '',
>   expected a step expression.

Hence I'm a little bit stuck. I think I'm on the right path with using nodes() inside a CROSS APPLY, but I can't get what I need.

Can anyone help?

Comment: My goto link for shredding deadlock XML is [here](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/code-library/shred-deadlock-graph/)

Comment: Thanks Martin, that helped a heck of a lot. Looks like i was on the right path with CROSS APPLY, I just need to employ an extra one (obvious when you think about it). I'll reply with the full script that provides the answer.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the script I already wrote for that: http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/tsqltuesday17usingapplytodemystifydeadlocks

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I can't use your script because it refers to //resource-list/keylock whereas, as you can see above, there is no keylock only metadatalock & objectlock. I need something that will parse out that information regardless of the names of those elements.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Martin Smith who left a comment containing a link that led me to this solution:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<resource-list>
  <metadatalock subresource="DATA_SPACE" classid="data_space_id = 65601" dbid="7" id="lockb0553200" mode="X">
    <owner-list>
      <owner id="process806e5b88" mode="Sch-S" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
      <waiter id="process11e2cb708" mode="Sch-M" requestType="convert" />
    </waiter-list>
  </metadatalock>
  <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="98099390" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="" id="lockbe2cfc00" mode="Sch-M" associatedObjectId="98099390">
    <owner-list>
      <owner id="process11e2cb708" mode="Sch-M" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
      <waiter id="process806e5b88" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait" />
    </waiter-list>
  </objectlock>
</resource-list>'
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#resourceList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #resourceList;
SELECT  [resource-list]=@xml
INTO    #resourceList

SELECT  MainLock.Process.query('.') AS node
FROM    #resourceList
CROSS APPLY [resource-list].nodes('//resource-list') AS Lock ( List )
CROSS APPLY Lock.List.nodes('*') AS MainLock (Process)
```

Basically just need to CROSS APPLY again. I also didn't know about .nodes('*') which is also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's no need for a second CROSS APPLY...NODES():

```
SELECT  Lock.List.query('.') AS node
FROM    #resourceList
CROSS APPLY [resource-list].nodes('/resource-list/*') AS Lock (List)
```

ML

Comment: See, I *knew* you'd be able to help Matija :)

Thanks, that's awesome.